# How to fetch shortlog data from CLI to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a repo in gerrit. I want execute a command line where I can get the shortlog data for my project.

[Say for instance](https://review.openstack.org/gitweb?p=stackforge%2Ffuel-library.git;a=shortlog;h=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerrit itself doesn't have remote `git log`-equivalent functionality, but you can install e.g. [Gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) (used by Openstack), [cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/), or [Gitiles](http://code.google.com/p/gitiles/) to get a web interface towards the gits.

Gerrit *does* have a [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html) that allows various types of queries for e.g. changes, but it doesn't cover all commits in the gits, only those that were uploaded for review in Gerrit.